# How do I manage repeting rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I organise this triple column data-set by removing the repeting elements.

```
Country       Year      Temperature
US            1990       25
US            1990       27 
US            1990       24
US            1991       26
Canada        1990       20
 .             .          .
```

Into

```
Country      Year        AvgTemp
US           1990           25.33
US            1991          26
Canada       1990           20
```

I can use groupby to do so for just the  'Year' and 'Temp' columns. But what if 3 columns are involved.

(P.S. I am new to pandas )

Comment: This is just: `df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['Temperature'].mean()`

Comment: To match your expected output with the new column name, use named aggregations instead: `df.groupby(['Country', 'Year']).agg(AvgTemp=('Temperature', 'mean')).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple variables inside groupby() like this

```
df.groupby(['Country','Year'])['Temp'].mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Year']).mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'Temperature':'AvgTemp'})
```